# Set up robo3t to connect to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm new to mongodb, and learning as i'm going. In my new team there isn't much documentation so i'm filling in gaps myself

There is mongodb set up that i finally managed to resolce access issues to and connect to with mongodb command line via the connection string below. (And based on my understanding, the community version of mongodb does not support this, i needed to use some server enterprise version which thankfully was free)

While i have minimum access to db now, it is quite a hassle to work with just the command line

> mongo.exe
> "mongodb://serv1.unix.me:10001,serv2.unix.me:10002,serv3.unix.me:10003/abc?replicaSet=example"
> --authenticationMechanism=GSSAPI --authenticationDatabase=$external --username "user@testdomain.me.com" --password "pAssw0rd!" -ssl --sslCAFile C:\files\ca.pem

I have Robo3T - 1.3 but no matter how many times i try to apply above connection string into the robo3t connection window, i keep getting various errors.
Part of me is worried that i need to use the enterprise version of robo3t (which isn't free)

Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: Alternately, if there is a better free gui that can apply my connection string, then i would be open to switching away from robo3t

Comment: For alternative GUI, I've been using mongoDB Compass for a while and it is quite a powerful tool for me. https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass

Comment: Check out the 'authentication setting', 'ssl settings', and 'replica set connection settings` sections of https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-connect-your-mongodb-deployments-to-robo-3t